# Are theses verses strictly hexametric?

Tags: scansion, metre

I've composed the following two verses in Latin (an allusion to the *prooemium* of Vergil's *Aeneis*:

> Annos virumque cano Scolae qui ab origine
>   ad probationem fecit nos inscitis ad sapientos

I would scan them the following way:

> *- v v - v v - - - -v v - x*
>   *- v v - v v - - - v v - v v - x*

However, I often mess up the *muta cum liquida*. Are these verses strict hexameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately it does not quite scan right.
Here are the problems I found:

- The second syllable of the first line, *-nōs*, is long for two reasons: the vowel is long and followed by two consonants.
- The *o* in *sc(h)ola* is short, so the first syllable is metrically short even though it has stress in prose.
- I'm not quite sure how you intended to scan the end of the first line. There is an elision between *qui* and *ab*. Did you perhaps intend to elide at the line break, too? The only long syllable in *orīgine* is the second one.
- The long syllables of *probātiōnem* don't quite match your scansion.
- Frankly, I have trouble seeing how the scansion of the second line is supposed to go. The ending *ad sapientos* matches your scansion and works well, but I can't quite see how the rest works.

In addition, there is a grammatical problem.
If you make someone from ignorant to wise, then *aliquem inscitum sapientem facis*.
(Also, the plural accusative ending is slightly off: it should be *sapientes*.)
Both words are in accusative without prepositions, and there is some possibility of confusion, too.
I don't think the English structure of "making someone from something to something" can work as you write in Latin.

I'm sorry if this sounds harsh, but I wanted to list the problems honestly.
I think the text is good prose apart from the one lapse, but the metric part does not quite work.

Here is my offer (with prose translation):

> *Tempora cara cano, quae tu schola cara dedisti;
>
>   te inscia turba intrans meminit sapiens abitura.*
>   I sing dear times, which you dear school gave;
>   the ignorant entering crowd remembers you when it is about to exit wise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This wasn't supposed to be prose, just a farewell text to a high school teacher. Thus, my knowledge is quite limited. I simply didn't know that one would put an elision between qui and ab. "quab" sounded so silly I dismissed that idea quickly.

Comment: Nice elision: Aeneid often uses elision to create jostling in the crowd.

Comment: @Hugh In addition to following metric requirements, I was trying to get a certain feeling of congestion to the uneducated crowd with elisions. I'm glad if it actually worked!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but this does not scan correctly.

First, the meter in your first line is missing a beat in your description, though, it's there I see in the line itself.

1. The o in *annos* is long by position, because it is followed by two consonants. Same with the u in *virumque*.
2. *qui* is elided before *ab*.
3. The a in *probationem* is long, as is the second *o*. The makes the first line scan `- u - u - - |`, since it is also followed by two consonants.
4. The dative/ablative plural of first/second declension adjectives is long.

Comment: I agree that there are problems. However, the attempt inspired me to try a little something myself in hexameter, and the original idea is good.